# Arguments & Options Manipulation in Multiple Bash Scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

**EDIT (Feb 24):** See bottom of the post for extra information, examples, and code.

There has been some downtime at work lately, so I decided to pick up some Bash scripting and automate the process of building our products. Here's a simplified version of our setup:

- There are three types of code bases - base libraries, old interfaces, and new interfaces
- Building is done in two steps - #1 setting the environment(al variables) and #2 compiling an executable / package; both of those are done with scripts, **some of which take command line arguments, and some don't**.
- Each code base uses a different `set-env` and `build` scripts (so the scripts directory could have things like `libs-set-env.sh`, `old-if-set-env.sh`, `new-if-set-env.sh`, `libs-build.sh`, etc...)

So. What I wanted to do is create some (combination of) Bash functions and scripts that would:

- Detect which code base's directory I am currently in
- Parse through any number of command line options / arguments. I've been using `getopts` in my attempts.

  - Some options are just flags (e.g. `-v` for verbose output) and some require a value (e.g. -`version 3.0`)
- Run the appropriate `set-env` script
- Run the appropriate `build` script

First I tried putting all this in a single `.sh` file. I ran into a problem where some of the build scripts would try to read my own command line arguments as if they were meant for them. So I'd run something like `~/myscript.sh -v` and would get an error like

```
~/scripts/build-base-libs.sh: line X: cd: -v: invalid option  
cd: usage: cd [-L|-P] [dir]
```

because `build-base-libs.sh` checks if the argument passed to it as either `--debug` or `--release` and if it's not (if it is, for example, `-v`), it treats it as a filepath and passes it to a `cd` call. Which is fine for the original script, but it messes up my wrapper. So **question #1**: can I still put everything in a single .sh file, but somehow avoid this issue (call the appropriate `build` scripts with only a subset or none of the original command line arguments, maybe?)?

When this didn't work, I tried splitting the functionality - so I would have mysetenv.sh and mybuild.sh, and have the former parse through my own command line arguments, and then call the latter with any or none of the original options (so if I run `~/mysetenv.sh -g -version 3.0`, I could choose whether to then call `~/mybuild.sh` with `-g`, with `-version 3.0`, with both, or with neither). Except I apparently don't know enough about Bash to make this run - when I run `~/mysetenv.sh` I don't actually see any of the output I am supposed to see from `mybuild.sh`. I *suspect* it has to do with child processes and subshells, but I just don't know... I also tried creating a small bash function in `~/.bashrc` and then have that function call the other two scripts, but ran into the same problem.

So... advise me, please?

### --- EDIT (Feb 24) ---

For simplicity's sake, I've reduced the number of possible situations. Let's assume I am going to be running my script with the following options and arguments:
`~/myscript.sh -c -v ver.3.0 --debug`
where `-c` just sets some flag, `-v` makes it so I need to append "ver.3.0" to the end of the build command, and `--debug` is an argument handled by the `build` scripts, it's not one of my own (so I'll need to pass it along, if it's provided).

Generally, my script should do the following:

#### 1) Parse through (my custom) options

Nothing fancy about those. I reset the OPTIND variable to make sure I always read everything

```
OPTIND=1
while getopts "cv:" OPTION; do
    "c") echo "Option -c" ;;
    "v") echo "Option -v ( = ${OPTARG})" ;;
    "?") echo "Unknown option."
done
```

#### 2) Choose the `setenv` command and run it

Both `setenv` and `build` scripts are designed to handle command line arguments, but I myself never pass any to the `setenv`s - only to `build`s, and even then only if the argument is the value of the `-v` option. So my `setenv` script is `/development/scripts/setenv_script.sh`, I would want to run

`. /development/scripts/setenv_script.sh # no options, ignoring that --debug from before`

First, without ignoring the `--debug` (because even without the `${@:OPTIND}` part, I get exactly the same error):

```
SETENV_COMMAND=". /development/scripts/setenv_script.sh" # Which will then call setenv_script_2.sh, which will call setenv_script_3.sh
echo eval "${SETENV_COMMAND} ${@:OPTIND}"
eval "${SETENV_COMMAND} ${@:OPTIND}" # I believe this should call the SETENV_COMMAND with anything after the OPTIND index...
```

I get the following error:

```
eval . /development/scripts/setenv_script.sh
/development/scripts/setenv_script_2.sh: line 104: cd: ver.3.0: No such file or directory
```

Relevant sections of `setenv_script_2.sh` include:

```
60 for option in $*; do
61     case $option in
62         "--release") ... ;;
63         "--debug") ... ;;
64         "--help") ... ;;
65         *) src_path=$option ;;
66     esac
67 done
...
103 if [ -n "${src_path}" ]; then
104     src_dir=$(cd -P ${src_path}; pwd -P)
105 else
106     src_dir=$(pwd -P)
```

So, as far as I can tell, `setenv_script.sh` is being called with no arguments (as shown by the `echo`; though I expected to get that `--debug`...), which is what I want, but one of the scripts called by *it* still treats "ver.3.0" as an argument - which I don't want it to. I want "ver.3.0" to be passed to the `build` script, and `setenv` to run with no arguments.

Is there a way for me to update `$@` / `$*`? So that, after I read my options, I can say "alright, there are 0 command line arguments, run `setenv_script.sh` passed to it and its children"? And then, when I am done with that, I can say "okay, now let's run `build.sh`, but if the `-v` option has been set, we'll give it its value as the only command line argument"?

#### 3) Choose the `build` command and run it

Not quite there yet.

Comment: It is really hard to answer any of your questions without you showing some of the code that is not doing what you want it to do.

Comment: I second Markku, please provide some code. On a side note, I think no child script "argument inheritance" could occur unless you explicitly pass arguments on by means of $*/$@ (general case).

Comment: I'll edit my post on Monday then, too much hassle to access work computers from home.

Comment: There, added a bunch of new info. It feels like I am getting close, but not close enough... =\